# PHP5-Mcrypt install error no installation candidate

Tags: php, linux, server, debian, vps

I want to install PHP5-Mcrypt in my Debian server . but when i run this command "apt-get install php5-mcrypt" i got an error like:

Apt-get install php5-mcrypt
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Package php5-mcrypt is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-mcrypt' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to try if this doesn't work is installing the module from source. Get the PHP source code so that you have access to the phpize utility. Then, grab the module source.

```
cd php-5.x.x/ext/mcrypt
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Although if I recall correctly, the apt-get PHP installation has this module already. From the command line run

```
php -i | grep mcrypt
```

Comment: how can i get the php source and how can i find the source for php5-mcrypt?

Comment: From the PHP website